# Why does the blade height goes on decreasing in a multi-stage axial flow compressor?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

The axial compressors used in jet engines have their blade heights in decreasing order in the direction of the flow.

Answer (score 2):

The blade size reduction is to achieve large pressure rises.the pressure is proportional to the volume.Axial flow compressors produce a continuous decelerating flow of compressed gas,for high efficiency and large mass flow rate, particularly in relation to their cross-section.the casing around these blades also reduces.high-pressure gas enters a turbine, where it expands down to the exhaust turbine.

Comment: + Right. As the air is squeezed, its volume decreases.